# How to pass flag option in CopyHere

Tags: windows, shell, fonts, vbscript, alert

I see in this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere
) that we can pass flag to remove this type of modal :

[image]

But actually nothing works, the modals don't go away

My code to install font, that I want without alert modal:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = CStr(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Const FONTS = &H14&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFontFolder = objShell.Namespace(FONTS)
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    objFontFolder.CopyHere objFile.Path, 16
Next
```

Comment: This might help point you in the right direction - [How do I pass option flags to Folder.CopyHere in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391007)

Comment: Might also be useful - [How to implement Bit Flags in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70747551)

Comment: You might be better off just [using FSO to copy the folders](https://serverfault.com/a/362265/199051).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Boxes should be hidden or confirm per vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70173260/windows-boxes-should-be-hidden-or-confirm-per-vbs)

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178761/15764378) will help?